# .net difference between right shift and left shift keys

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard

I am currently working on an application which requires different behaviour based on whether the user presses the right or left shift key (RShiftKey, LShiftKey), however when either of these keys is pressed I only see ShiftKey | Shift.

Is there something wrong with my keyboard? (laptop) do I need a new keyboard driver/keyboard in order to send the different key commands maybe...

This is a pretty massive problem at the moment, as there is no way of testing that the code works (apart from unit tests).  Anyone had any experience of the different shift/alt/ctrl keys?

Comment: I see .net, but what is your platform? WPF? Winforms? Console? Silverlight?

Comment: Sorry good point - it's simply Winforms.  Though I guess a key stroke is a key stroke, or is that only the tip of my naivety on this subject..

Comment: Apparently distinguishing between left and right puts this into the category of "virtual key" which requires a little extra effort to work with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this post will help you or not, but it looks like you may have to mess with InteropServices and Diagnostics:

[MSDN Forum: How to send Left/Right shift key](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/dd6406e8-b6bf-4166-82a0-6d533def38a5)

**Edit:** I finally figured out how to make GetAsyncKeyState() work, as adrianbanks revealed.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys vKey);

private void theForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Left");
        }
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Right");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - yeah I look at this post before but it only talks about sending the key stroke.  What's odd is that the keyboard itself simply never sends this "Keys".  So I assume I need to modify something in Windows to allow my keyboard to support this, or get a new driver, or both.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293.aspx) Win32 method. You can add a pInvoke call to it using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);
```

and then handle the `KeyDown` event on your form:

```
private void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Left Shift :  " + (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey) < 0));
    Console.WriteLine("Right Shift: " + (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey) < 0));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar need to differentiate between the left and right shift and control keys. Here's my rather-longer but possibly better solution. If you want to catch the alt keys, you'll need to override some other things to prevent them from activating any menu(s). `((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF)` should give the repeat count, but it never seems to go above 2.

```
    protected override bool ProcessKeyMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN || m.Msg == WM_KEYUP) && ((int)m.WParam == VK_CONTROL || (int)m.WParam == VK_SHIFT))
        {
           KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.None);
           switch ((OemScanCode)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0x1FF))
            {
                case OemScanCode.LControl:
                    e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.LControlKey);
                    break;
                case OemScanCode.RControl:
                    e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.RControlKey);
                    break;
                case OemScanCode.LShift:
                    e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.LShiftKey);
                    break;
                case OemScanCode.RShift:
                    e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.RShiftKey);
                    break;
                default:
                    if ((int)m.WParam == VK_SHIFT)
                        e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.ShiftKey);
                    else if ((int)m.WParam == VK_CONTROL)
                        e = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.ControlKey);
                    break;
            }
            if (e.KeyData != Keys.None)
            {
                if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
                    OnKeyDown(e);
                else
                    OnKeyUp(e);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessKeyMessage(ref m);
    }

    #region Scan code & window message stuff
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    const int VK_SHIFT = 0x10;
    const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
    /// <summary>
    /// Alt key
    /// </summary>
    const int VK_MENU = 0x12;

    /// <summary>
    /// List of scan codes for standard 104-key keyboard US English keyboard
    /// </summary>
    enum OemScanCode
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ` ~
        /// </summary>
        BacktickTilde = 0x29,
        /// <summary>
        /// 1 !
        /// </summary>
        N1 = 2,
        /// <summary>
        /// 2 @
        /// </summary>
        N2 = 3,
        /// <summary>
        /// 3 #
        /// </summary>
        N3 = 4,
        /// <summary>
        /// 4 $
        /// </summary>
        N4 = 5,
        /// <summary>
        /// 5 %
        /// </summary>
        N5 = 6,
        /// <summary>
        /// 6 ^
        /// </summary>
        N6 = 7,
        /// <summary>
        /// 7 &
        /// </summary>
        N7 = 8,
        /// <summary>
        /// 8 *
        /// </summary>
        N8 = 9,
        /// <summary>
        /// 9 (
        /// </summary>
        N9 = 0x0A,
        /// <summary>
        /// 0 )
        /// </summary>
        N0 = 0x0B,
        /// <summary>
        /// - _
        /// </summary>
        MinusDash = 0x0C,
        /// <summary>
        /// = +
        /// </summary>
        Equals = 0x0D,
        Backspace = 0x0E,
        Tab = 0x0F,
        Q = 0x10,
        W = 0x11,
        E = 0x12,
        R = 0x13,
        T = 0x14,
        Y = 0x15,
        U = 0x16,
        I = 0x17,
        O = 0x18,
        P = 0x19,
        /// <summary>
        /// [ {
        /// </summary>
        LBracket = 0x1A,
        /// <summary>
        /// ] }
        /// </summary>
        RBracket = 0x1B,
        /// <summary>
        /// | \ (same as pipe)
        /// </summary>
        VerticalBar = 0x2B,
        /// <summary>
        /// | \ (same as vertical bar)
        /// </summary>
        Pipe = 0x2B,
        CapsLock = 0x3A,
        A = 0x1E,
        S = 0x1F,
        D = 0x20,
        F = 0x21,
        G = 0x22,
        H = 0x23,
        J = 0x24,
        K = 0x25,
        L = 0x26,
        /// <summary>
        /// ; :
        /// </summary>
        SemiColon = 0x27,
        /// <summary>
        /// ' "
        /// </summary>
        Quotes = 0x28,
        // Unused
        Enter = 0x1C,
        LShift = 0x2A,
        Z = 0x2C,
        X = 0x2D,
        C = 0x2E,
        V = 0x2F,
        B = 0x30,
        N = 0x31,
        M = 0x32,
        /// <summary>
        /// , <
        /// </summary>
        Comma = 0x33,
        /// <summary>
        /// . >
        /// </summary>
        Period = 0x34,
        /// <summary>
        /// / ?
        /// </summary>
        Slash = 0x35,
        RShift = 0x36,
        LControl = 0x1D,
        LAlternate = 0x38,
        SpaceBar = 0x39,
        RAlternate = 0x138,
        RControl = 0x11D,
        /// <summary>
        /// The menu key thingy
        /// </summary>
        Application = 0x15D,
        Insert = 0x152,
        Delete = 0x153,
        Home = 0x147,
        End = 0x14F,
        PageUp = 0x149,
        PageDown = 0x151,
        UpArrow = 0x148,
        DownArrow = 0x150,
        LeftArrow = 0x14B,
        RightArrow = 0x14D,
        NumLock = 0x145,
        NumPad0 = 0x52,
        NumPad1 = 0x4F,
        NumPad2 = 0x50,
        NumPad3 = 0x51,
        NumPad4 = 0x4B,
        NumPad5 = 0x4C,
        NumPad6 = 0x4D,
        NumPad7 = 0x47,
        NumPad8 = 0x48,
        NumPad9 = 0x49,
        NumPadDecimal = 0x53,
        NumPadEnter = 0x11C,
        NumPadPlus = 0x4E,
        NumPadMinus = 0x4A,
        NumPadAsterisk = 0x37,
        NumPadSlash = 0x135,
        Escape = 1,
        PrintScreen = 0x137,
        ScrollLock = 0x46,
        PauseBreak = 0x45,
        LeftWindows = 0x15B,
        RightWindows = 0x15C,
        F1 = 0x3B,
        F2 = 0x3C,
        F3 = 0x3D,
        F4 = 0x3E,
        F5 = 0x3F,
        F6 = 0x40,
        F7 = 0x41,
        F8 = 0x42,
        F9 = 0x43,
        F10 = 0x44,
        F11 = 0x57,
        F12 = 0x58,
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Thanks D'nar! This solution seems must better to Me then any others. Mainly because there are no other calls, this just works with the original data. So it is longer, but actually faster and more stable.

Comment: Very handy to interpret keyboard input by position (e.g. WASD in gaming) regardless of the actual keyboards layout.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks guys, good solution there.  In the mean time here's my own "hacky" way of doing it from the override of ProcessCmdKey:

```
public override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (msg.LParam.ToInt32() == 0x2a0001)
        LastShiftKey = ShiftKeys.NumericShift;
        else if (msg.LParam.ToInt32() == 0x360001)
            LastShiftKey = ShiftKeys.AlphaShift;
    etc....
}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the one marked as answer; `GetAsyncKeyState` cannot be relied on to give correct results (it may report the key is not pushed, despite your application receiving an event that it is), whereas your solution here can be relied on (though those specific codes may vary across different OSs).

Comment: Mr AH: Take a look at Dr. D'nar 's solution. It is much more understandable.