# confusion between using Keys.Shift and Keys.ShiftKey

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms:
I have some code like this:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState((int)Keys.ShiftKey) != 0)
{
    nShift = (nShift | 1);
}
```

If I change the if to `Keys.Shift` then it is working correctly like tabbing forward but if then it breaks the tabbing-backward which is TAB+SHIFT keys on keyborad.  but I want to have both forward and backward tabbing to work. How can I change this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.net difference between right shift and left shift keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569268/net-difference-between-right-shift-and-left-shift-keys) is the answer. we should say Keys.LShiftKey and Keys.RShiftKey

Answer (score 3):

The ShiftKey value determines if the event was raised due to the Shift key being pressed down/up/etc. The Shift value is a *modifier*, which can be combined with other keys.

So if the value is `A + Shift`, then that means the user pressed the A key while holding down the Shift key.

You don't give enough information to indicate why tabbing would be affected, but I suspect you are not handling the case there the Control and Shift modifiers are specified properly (along with the Tab key). Or you are handling the event and preventing the normal tabbing from occurring.